# mysql + update top n

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I've got a query like this:

```
update  table
set     status = 1
where   status = 2;
```

but I'd only like to do this to the top 400. I tried adding a 'limit 0, 400' (like I would in a query) but that didn't work. I did some searching and mysql doesn't seem to support the TOP(n) command as sql server does.

Any idea how I'd do this?

edit: for future reference, I was using the following style for selects, which worked fine:

```
select  * 
from    table
where   ... limit 0, 400;
```

but in the update it wouldn't work with the "0, " for whatever reason. I would consider this inconsistent and ambiguous behaviour, but oh well.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
UPDATE  table
SET     status = 1
WHERE   status = 2
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 400
```

Checked in `MySQL 5.2.0-falcon-alpha-community-nt-log`, confirmed working.

In your case it's `0` in `LIMIT 0, 400` that does not work.

You cannot use the lower bound in `UPDATE`'s `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
update  table
set     status = 1
where   status = 2
LIMIT 400
```

You can also put an order by clause

```
update  table
set     status = 1
where   status = 2
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 400
```

Comment: This would update every row because of the semicolon after the 2. no?

Comment: I think the semicolon is just mistakingly pasted from the original query, it has no point here.

Answer (score 1):

for future reference don't forget to set the safe mode off

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
update YOUR_DATABASE_NAME.TABLE_NAME
set COLUMN_NAM = 0
limit 400;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

MySQL for example does not allow you to update records to prevent you from making mistakes with something called safe mode, so you will have to disable it to be able to update your records.

The other syntax is pretty forward.
limit will restrict the number of records returned to a number of your choosing.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it