# SELECT then UPDATE Query

Tags: mysql

Im tryng to combine this 2 queries and having a hard time doing so:

```
UPDATE applicantinfo SET Section = 1
```

and

```
SELECT Section from applicantinfo ORDER BY SCORE DESC LIMIT 50
```

anyway I can do this?

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.  I have no idea what you intend by "combining" these two queries.

Comment: you are updating `applicantinfo` and selecting data from `applicantinfo`. please help us SO users by giving some data and desired result.

Comment: Are you looking for something like: *`UPDATE applicantinfo SET Section = 1 where score in ( select distinct score from applicantinfo order by 1 desc ) limit 50;`* ?

Comment: Are you trying to set `Section = 1` on the first 50 rows selected by the later query?

Comment: thats what im tryng to do @viniciusmunich-AssabetTech :)

Comment: unfortunately I really dont know how. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking to update the top 50 records of your table, you can do so by the following query.

```
UPDATE applicantinfo SET Section = 1
WHERE SCORE IN
(SELECT DISTINCT SCORE FROM applicantinfo ORDER BY SCORE)
LIMIT 50
```

There is a similar post in SO for this issue. Here is the link.

**[mysql + update top n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726386/mysql-update-top-n)**