# MySql Deadlocks / Commit not unlocking in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ado.net

Can anyone tell me why the following code can deadlock? I'm simulating our webserver on multiple threads in a console app.

The console app has 5 threads and updates 250 records on each thread.

I am finding that transaction.Commit() is not enough, I will get deadlocks, so it clearly isn't releasing the locks at that point.

Unless I put the transaction.Dispose() in and the Sleep(50ms), I consistently get deadlocks on innodb. If I turn the code into a sproc, then the sleep needs to be bigger to avoid deadlocks. I'm not sure it does avoid them totally actually, need to run it with more threads.

Closing the connection after the transaction is more reliable but in the web app ideally we want to have a connection per request for performance.

Also putting transaction.Dispose() is far more reliable in terms of avoiding deadlocks, than using (var transaction = ...

We are using .NET currently, not .NET core.

I would bet if I write the same program using SqlClient for Sql/Server it will work - I'm going to try that tomorrow.

Can anyone explain this? What am I doing wrong?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("GenerateBarcodesTestConsoleApp");

    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;

    var threads = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);

    Parallel.ForEach(threads, t =>
    {
        GenerateBarcodes2(t, connectionString, 250);
    });

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void GenerateBarcodes2(int thread, string connectionString, int numberToGenerate)
{
    using (var con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();

        var sql1 = "SELECT p.barcode, p..barcode_id " +
                    "FROM p_barcode p " +
                    "WHERE p.company_id = 1 " +
                    "AND SUBSTRING(p.barcode,1,2) = 'OK' " +
                    "AND players.in_use = 0 " +
                    "LIMIT 1 " +
                    "FOR UPDATE;";

        var sql2 = "UPDATE p_barcode SET in_use = 1 WHERE company_id = 1 AND barcode_id = ?barcode_id AND in_use = 0";

        for (int b = 0; b < numberToGenerate; b++)
        {
            using (var transaction = con.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
            {
                string barcode = string.Empty;
                int barcodeId = 0;

                using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql1, con, transaction))
                {
                    var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        barcode = (string)rdr["barcode"];
                        barcodeId = (int)rdr["barcode_id"];
                    }
                    rdr.Close();

                    Console.WriteLine(barcode);
                }

                if (barcodeId != 0)
                {
                    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql2, con, transaction))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("barcode_id", barcodeId);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                transaction.Commit();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
            //transaction.Dispose();
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just execute UPDATE statement which uses limited SELECT? No transactions are needed, you can reserve all 250 barcodes in single shot. Database is happy. [Update. top n rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/726428/10646316)

Comment: A single (update) statement uses implicit transactions, but that is not enough in this example, if I took off transaction processing, multiple threads would get the same value, which is not the idea at all, if many users are doing this on a website, each user (thread in the above example) needs to get to a unique record in the table. We need to lock the record so another thread running at the same time doesn't get the same record. I need the threads because they are simulating many users using our website at once. Yes we don't have that many users but I'm trying to ensure the database is solid

Comment: no rdms like to get bombarded with tansactions. It will lock, but for testing you must write n threads that will connect to the database ,a every connection will use up resources

Comment: Both [MySQL-8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) and [MariaDB-10.6](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select/#skip-locked) have `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` such that your multiple threads can grab a row, skipping the existing locked rows.

Comment: Please add from the output of "show engine innodb status" the part with "latest detected deadlock" (it will give more details what locks conflict) as well as the output of "show create table p_barcode", especially all indexes.

Comment: show engine innodb status doesn't show much at the moment, I will run the tests and try again. @danblack you might have something there, I wasn't aware of that, I kind of assumed that would be what it would do. I'll give this a try.

Comment: I'm on innodb locally, mariadb in production at some point in the future. So I can't try SKIP LOCKED as yet.

Comment: What is `players`???

Comment: A `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` leads to a random result.

Comment: What indexes are on the table(s)?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

In MariaDb, SKIP LOCKED is the solution to prevent deadlocks.

There isn't a perfect solution to prevent deadlocks, without redesigning the system to avoid two threads trying to update the same record at the same time, however adding a small sleep after commit transaction appears to help massively. 20ms was about right on my dev machines.

Does this suggest that commit returns before the database has actually committed the transaction and released the locks? Either way, this behaviour is the same for INNODB and MARIADB.

Comment: A deadlock tells you there was a serious problem.  You should not ignore it.

Comment: SKIP LOCKED is the definite solution in this scenario. The deadlock is because one user comes along and locks the record, then before the user has updated the inuse to 1, another user comes along and locks the same record. The deadlock occurs when the first user updates the inuse to 1 so there is no record left for the second user to pick. Its been suggested on INNODB that the second user does a retry at that point and they will pick up the next record. I think its just the design - we can't use an identity column because we want a different identity per record so that would mean many tables.